# r error in rep(value, length.out = n) : attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to write a function that can apply another function to a number of data.frames at one time. The data.frames are named DATA_1, DATA_2, etc. and the variable 'actioncol' is to indicate the column that has to be changed. This is my code so far:

```
gsubFUN <- function(name, actioncol, ...){
  df.vec <- ls(pattern =  paste("name", "*", sep="_"), envir=.GlobalEnv)
  for(ii in 1:length(df.vec)){
  DATA <- get(df.vec[ii])
  DATA[,actioncol] <- gsub(pattern.vec[ii], replace.vec[ii], DATA[,actioncol])
  assign(paste(name, ii, sep = "_"),DATA, envir = .GlobalEnv)    
  }
}
```

I am aware that my code may be quite messed up, but it does work. Since I would like the outer function to apply other functions (not just gsub) on the data.frames, too, I tried to replace it with a variable:

```
multiDfFUN <- function(name, actioncol, FUN, ...){
  df.vec <- ls(pattern =  paste(name, "*", sep="_"), envir=.GlobalEnv)
  for(ii in 1:length(df.vec)){
  DATA <- get(df.vec[ii])
  DATA[,actioncol] <- match.fun(FUN)
  assign(paste(name, ii, sep = "_"),DATA, envir = .GlobalEnv)    
  }
}

multiDfFUN(name="audi", actioncol="color", FUN=gsub, pattern=pattern.vec[ii],
       replacement=replace.vec[ii], x=DATA[,actioncol])
```

However, this now returns an error message:

```
error in rep(value, length.out = n) : 
   attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'
```

I don't even understand the meaning of this. Searching the web wouldn't help it either. Could the arguments pattern, replacement & x when calling the function be the reason for this? I would be really glad if somebody could enlighten me on this issue or even point me to a simple solution (if there is any).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you say searching won't help?  I just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17685502/271616) by searching SO for the error message.

Comment: I read through that post earlier, too, didn't clarify it for me, sorry.

Comment: Are you under the impression that `<- match.fun(FUN)` calls the function `FUN` on `DATA[,actioncol]`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Guess that's wrong?

Comment: Quite wrong. You could simply replace `gsub(...)` with `FUN(...)` perhaps. But I'll leave you with my standard advice here that this function is quite a mess. Bar `get` and `assign` from your lexicon; pass arguments to functions as needed and return values. Don't reach across environments for objects you need and then don't assign into the global environment. It is terrible stylistically and will just create more problems than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks for your adivce. As mentioned before, I didn't like it myself. I've done a little bit r programming before and I never used `get`or `assign`and intuitively I would have gone for a different solution. However, I'm writing this code for a class at university where we were repeatedly encouraged to it that way.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
DATA[,actioncol] <- match.fun(FUN)
```

... is attempting to assign functions (not function names) to items in a dataframe. That's not going to succeed. And then you write:

```
assign(paste(name, ii, sep = "_"),DATA, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

That effort is very contrary to the preferred programing style of R. Assigning to the GlobalEnv from within the function body should only be attempted by people who know what that error message meant. `match.fun` returns a functions so I image you would wnat to do something like this:

```
 DATA[,actioncol] <-  match.fun(FUN)( DATA[,actioncol] )
 return(DATA)
```

And then call it like:

```
DATAnew <- multiDfFUN(name="audi", actioncol="color", FUN=gsub, 
                      pattern=pattern.vec[ii],
                      replacement=replace.vec[ii], x=DATA[,actioncol])
```

Since we have no example data to work with, I will leave this as an untested guess.

Note added in proof:

```
 fortunes::fortune("understand why")
```

> The only people who should use the assign function are those who fully understand
>   why you should never use the assign function.
>      -- Greg Snow
>         R-help (July 2009)

Answer (score 1):

Examns kept me quite busy, that's why I'm just answering now. DWin's suggestions actually helped me get the function to work as intended.

I also took all your warnings about `attach`in consideration. But as mentioned before, I did this code for an assignment where I was explicitly asked to use it. So this is what I ended up with:

```
MultiDfFUN <- function(df.vec, col.name, col.new="new", df.name, 
                       FUN, overwrite=F, ...){
 df.list <- list(NULL)
 for(ii in 1:length(df.vec)){
    DATA <- get(df.vec[ii])
    DATA[,col.new] <- FUN(DATA[,col.name],...)

    if(overwrite == TRUE){
      assign(paste(df.name, ii, sep = "_"),DATA, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }else{
      df.list[[ii]] <- DATA[,col.new]
    }
  }
  if(overwrite == FALSE) return(df.list)
}
```