# Why can't I assign a function with ifelse in R?

Tags: r, functional-programming

In R, when I try to assign a function via `ifelse`, I get the following error:

```
> my.func <- ifelse(cond, sqrt, identity)
Error in rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'builtin'
```

If `cond` is `FALSE`, the error looks equivalent, R complains about an

```
attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'
```

What can I do to assign one of two functions to a variable and what is going on here?

Comment: This question was inspired by and is related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685502).

Answer (score 5):

Because `ifelse` is vectorized and does not provide special cases for non-vectorized conditions, the arguments are replicated with `rep(...)`.  `rep(...)` fails for closures such as in the example though.

A workaround would be to temprarily wrap the functions:

```
my.func <- ifelse(cond, c(sqrt), c(identity))[[1]]
```

Comment: I would go with `switch` -- there are examples in many tutorials of how to use `switch` to grab different functions and apply them to the input.

Comment: ...or just use `my.func <- if(cond) sqrt else identity`. No need to abuse `ifelse`.

Comment: How could this be vectorised, if that was desired?

Answer (score 1):

@Joshua Ulrich's comment is a proper answer.  The correct way to accomplish conditional function assignment is a classic `if...else` rather than the vectorized `ifelse` method:

```
my.func <- if (cond) sqrt else identity
```