# Assigning letter grades to testscores in a table in R

Tags: r

```
classlist = read.table("classlist.txt", sep="\t", header=T)
classlist
Testscore <- runif(35,60,100)
classlist$Testscore <- Testscore
classlist
classlist$Grade <- function(Testscore) {
 if(Testscore>=95){
         grade = "A"`enter code here`
         } else if(Testscore>=90 & Testscore<95){
          grade = "A-"
         } else if(Testscore>=85 & Testscore<90){
         grade = "B+"
         } else if(Testscore>=80 & Testscore<85){
         grade = "B"
         } else if(Testscore>=75 & Testscore<80){
         grade = "B-"
         } else {grade = "C"}
     }
```

i want to assign the appropriate grades to the column grade in the table  have imported 
when i try this code the following error is mentioned :

```
Error in rep(value, length.out = nrows) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'
```

Comment: This might help you
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685502/in-r-getting-the-following-error-attempt-to-replicate-an-object-of-type-clos

Comment: You are assigning a function to `classlist$Grade`. For your code to work, you should first create the function `myfunc <- function(Testscore){...}` and then apply it `classlist$Grade <- myfunc(classlist$Testscore)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
classlist        <- data.frame(scores=runif(35,60,100))
classlist$grades <- cut(classlist$scores, 
                        breaks=c(0,seq(75,100,by=5)),
                        labels=c("C","B-","B","B+","A-","A"))
head(classlist,10)
#      scores grades
# 1  70.62035      C
# 2  74.88496      C
# 3  82.91413      B
# 4  96.32831      A
# 5  68.06728      C
# 6  95.93559      A
# 7  97.78701      A
# 8  86.43191     B+
# 9  85.16456     B+
# 10 62.47145      C
```

Good rule of thumb in R: when you have a string of `if` statements like that, there's almost always a better way. Read the documentation on `cut(...)`