# Replace only space between two words, not between words and symbol or words and numbers

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to use the stringr package in R to identify space(s) between words but not space(s) between words and symbols (or vice versa) or words and numbers (or vice versa), or symbols and numbers.

Based on what I could find it seems like [A-Za-z][:space:][a-zA-Z] should work. I'm obviously missing something but not sure what.

I've tried the stringr syntax with [A-Za-z][:space:][a-zA-Z], as well as regex(?) syntax for the spaces such as [A-Za-z]\s+[a-zA-Z]

```
str_replace_all(x, [A-Za-z][:space:][a-zA-Z], "_")
```

Sometimes an error I would get is "Error in rep(value, length.out = nrows) : attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'"

Comment: It would be useful and easy to help if you could add some input along with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
str_replace_all(x, "(?<=\\p{L})\\s(?=\\p{L})", "_")
gsub("(?<=\\p{L})\\s(?=\\p{L})", "_", x, perl=TRUE)
```

Or, if there are 1 or more spaces to be replaced with 1 `_`,

```
str_replace_all(x, "(?<=\\p{L})\\s+(?=\\p{L})", "_")
gsub("(?<=\\p{L})\\s+(?=\\p{L})", "_", x, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QhgfJG/1)

**Details**

- `(?<=\p{L})` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with any letter
- `\s` - a whitespace (`\s+` matches 1+ whitespaces)
- `(?=\p{L})` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with any letter.

**NOTE**:

- You should wrap the regex pattern with quotes to form a string literal
- If you want to only support ASCII letters, you may replace `\\p{L}` with `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: thanks for the thorough explanation. I noticed that I'm still running into the error ```Error in rep(value, length.out = nrows) : attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'```
any suggestions as to what might be causing it?

Comment: @dnmc See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685502/in-r-getting-the-following-error-attempt-to-replicate-an-object-of-type-clos