# Error message in R: "error to replicate an object of type 'closure'"

Tags: r, r-package, error-code, package-development

I am creating an R package where one function uses a vector that was created in another function. The vector is successfully created and assigned to the global environment (because I was having issues with calling a vector created in other function) in the first function:

```
sites <- function(...) {
  s <- c(...)
  assign(x = 's', value = s, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Then in the second function, I tried to call the vector `s` to influence the output:

```
dates <- function(date) {
  d <- rep(date, length(s))
  print(d)
}
```

However, when I run these functions, I get an error:

```
Error in rep(date, length(s)) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'
```

I saw the same error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685502/in-r-getting-the-following-error-attempt-to-replicate-an-object-of-type-clos) but did not fully understand it. I'm thinking the problem is with the environments or the functions being in a package, but I don't know how to fix it or understand why I keep getting this error.

Thanks in advance!

I tried:

```
sites(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
dates("10/24/2023")
```

I expected:

```
[1] "10/24/2023" "10/24/2023" "10/24/2023" "10/24/2023" "10/24/2023"
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me, just called from console.

Comment: The error message is clear: For some strange and unknown reason, the `date` vector isn't found and `rep` is passed the closure (a type of function) `date` (check `help("date")`). Likely the `sites` function wasn't actually run. The issue is probably related to the extremely bad practices in your code. Package code should never assign into the global environment. Functions should properly return their result. `s` should be an argument of `dates`.

Comment: @Roland makes some very pertinent points.  I would also add that running functions for their side effects (as you do with `sites`) is generally a bad idea.  They should explicitly return a value when their purpose is to create that value.  Also, you don't say *where* you are running your calls to `sites` and `dates`: within the package or outside the package.  If outside the package, have you exported them?  If not, that will explain why your error message refers to the built-in `date` function rather than your vector `date`.  [Hadley's book](https://r-pkgs.org/) contains excellent advice.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas to adjust my coding practices. I'm making appropriate fixes. Thank you!